# how to send id of a user in modals bootstrap

Tags: angular

i have done a looping in my code now i want to get the user id and show the data into a bootstrap model

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center single_user"
    *ngFor="let meals of mydata; let i = index;">
    <img src="../../assets/images/profilepic.png">
    {{meals.name}}
    
        <input type="text" readonly class="form-control-sm n" id="staticEmail2"
            value='{{ meals.deposited}}'>
    
    
        <!-- <input type="text" class="form-control-sm" formControlName="paid" id="id"
            value='{{ meals.paids}}'> -->
    
    <!-- <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2"
        (click)="sattle(meals.client_id, meals.deposited, meals.paids)">Settle -->
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2"
        data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" id="id" >W / D
    <i></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the ng-bootstrap modal to do this.
[Ng Bootstrap Modal Link](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples)